# MySQL finding duplicate items in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I just wanna ask if is it possible to make a query to see all the duplicate items between two tables? I've tried some solutions but it returns duplicated rows not duplicated items.

For example, I have these two tables:

table_a

> |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
>
> ..........................................
>
> | door | book | keys | shoe |
>
> | door | bags | desk | keys |
>
> | rice | fish | cake | shoe |

table_b

> |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
>
> | tape | fans | robe | spec |
>
> | keys | shoe | fans | room |
>
> | hall | pops | door | disc |

So, in the end it only returns all the items that has duplicates. For example,

> | door |
>
> | keys |
>
> | shoe |
>
> .....

I've tried a few queries but I still can't find a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by unpivoting the data and using `group by`:

```
select col
from (select a as col from table_a union all
      select b from table_a union all
      select c from table_a union all
      select d from table_a union all
      select a from table_b union all
      select b from table_b union all
      select c from table_b union all
      select d from table_b
     ) t
group by col
having count(*) > 1;
```

If the table is large, there are more efficient ways to unpivot than using `union all`.